# Jquery Looping through elements created at runtime

Tags: jquery, html, loops, foreach

i have a list that is passed to a page and the elements are created at runtime. I would like to loop through these elements and preform some action for each element. Under is my code:
for each person that gets created from this list i would like to preform a check on that person. Can someone help me i am only getting the check happening once:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#userId").each(function(i){
        if ($("#userId").val != '') {
            alert('not null' + i);
        }
    });                 
});
```

JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${person}" var="person">

<input= type="text" id="userId" value="${person.userid}" />
    First name:- ${person.fName} , Last Name:- ${person.lName}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The id selector, as the jquery documentation states: *Selects a single element with the given id attribute.* That's whay you're getting the check just once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot have multiple elements on a page with the same `id` attribute. try using classes instead.

try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".userId").each(function(i){
       if ($(this).val() != '') {
           alert('not null' + i);
       }
   });
});
```

Another thing to note is that .val is a method, so you need to call it to get the value. Use `.val()` instead of `.val`. As you have your code now, $(selector).val is a function, so it will never be the empty string you are testing it against.

Also your JSP should be something like:

```
<c:forEach items="${person}" var="person">

<input= type="text" class="userId" value="${person.userid}" />
    First name:- ${person.fName} , Last Name:- ${person.lName}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your loop will create multiple element with same ID, first change that. It is better to use class names instead.

```
<c:forEach items="${person}" var="person">

    <input= type="text" class="user" id="userId-${person.userid}" value="${person.userid}" />
       <!--             ^ Use Class &  ^ Id to uniquely identify the user -->
       First name:- ${person.fName} , Last Name:- ${person.lName}
</c:forEach>
```

Next you can use `.find()` to find even the dynamically generated element. But I recommend using my solutions using the `class` attribute.

```
$(".user").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
          alert('not null' + i);
    }
});
```

Comment: `.find` doesn't have anything to do with dynamically added elements. It is just a way of finding descendants of the current set of matched elements.

Comment: @Andbdrew, Actually it does. Please check to verify it `.find()` can find newly added elements to the DOM. (Did you downvote me for that reason?)

Comment: It is related to why I downvoted your answer, but there are other reasons too. The OP doesn't want to attach click events to these elements, so your script doesn't answer the question. Also, see the documentation about .find here http://api.jquery.com/find/ . It has nothing to do with dynamically adding events. It just allows you search within your current matched set. It's not that your statement about find was incorrect, it just has nothing to do with the issue at hand. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I agree with `click` event part, but I showed an example to the OP. I fixed it anyways. I however don't agree with your comments about `.find()`, clearly you are not in the state of understanding me. So thank you for the downvote.

Comment: as I said above, `.find` can find elements that were dynamically to a page, but that fact is not at all related to the question or solution.

Answer (score 2):

As @Andbdrew said, use a class instead of an id, as it will stop looking for more items after it finds the first that matches the id.

Also, you'll want to use `this` instead of `$("#userId")` inside our function.

So do something like this:

```
$(".userClass").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        alert('not null' + i);
    }
});
```

Comment: `.val` is a method and need to be called

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the typo.!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you select with TAG by jQuery. 
For example the element having your users list is a table with id tblUsers then you can itereate over runtime generated TRs or TDs as following:

```
$("#tblUsers tr").each(function(i){
        alert('td' + i);
 });
```

further if you have inputs in tds you can go deep in selection as

```
$("tblUsers tr td input")
```